# How to Pass Selected Parameters to Partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, partials

I am newer to Rails and am building a CMS, and need to allow the user to select a certain restaurant they own, whereby that selection will then be passed to a partial and the partial will display the campaigns that belong to that restaurnat. In short, the data model I have created is as such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :restaurants, dependent: :destroy
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    validates  :user_id, presence: true

    has_many :campaigns, dependent: :destroy
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

At present I have the `show` page for the users where the partials displaying the campaigns for the restaurant selected will display:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= gravatar_for @user %>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section>
            <% if @user.locations.any? %>
                <div>
                    <%= link_to "Start a Campaign", newcampaign_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
                </div>
                <%= link_to "Manage Locations", uploadlocations_path %>     
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to "Upload Locations", uploadlocations_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %> 
            <% end %>
        </section>
        <section>

            <%# disply list of restaurants%>

            <%= link_to "Add New Restaurant", newrestaurant_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
            <ul class ="campaigns">
                <%= render @restaurants %>
            </ul>

        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <% if @restaurants.any? %>

            <ol class="campaigns">
                <%= render @campaigns, object: @restaurants %>
            </ol>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller as (although incorrect):

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @restaurants = @user.restaurants.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @campaigns = @restaurants.first.campaigns.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

with the user able to click on the specific restaurant in the side menu at `render @restaurants`, which goes to the partial:

```
<ul>
    <span class="content">
        <%= link_to restaurant.name, '#' %>
    </class>
</ul>
```

At the moment this layout does not work work as I do not know how to pass the selected restaurant information back into the  tab in the show page to display the specific campaigns for that restaurant selected. How can I have a user click on a restaurant in the menu and send that specific restaurant selected back into the `<%= render @campaigns, object: @restaurants %>` in the users `show` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understand correctly, in the left menu you have a list of the restaurants and in the right menu you want to display the campaigns for a selected restaurant, right?

So, in the restaurant partial you'll want to create a link for that specific restaurant:

```
<ul>
  <span class="content">
    <%# We'll pass the page as well to keep pagination working %>
    <%= link_to restaurant.name, user_path(restaurant.user, restaurant_id: restaurant.id, page: params[:page]) %>
  </span>
</ul>
```

Perhaps you'll want to use nested resources (I'm not assume you're in the users controller since you're getting the user_id as id), if you're using nested resources and you're in the restaurants controller, the path should be something like: user_restaurant_path(restaurant.user, restaurant)

Then in the controller you wan't to find the specific restaurant you selected:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @restaurants = @user.restaurants.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @restaurant = @user.restaurants.find_by_id(params[:restaurant_id]) || @restaurants.first #in case no restaurant is selected, like the first time.
  @campaigns = @restaurant.campaigns if @restaurant
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Partials**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Firstly, let me give you some ideas regarding Rails Partials.

Partials in Rails are meant as a way to give you the ability to append modular layout-style HTML to your page without having to continuously rewrite it. It's basically like a "helper" for your Rails layouts.

I think you're getting confused with how Rails partials work in the front-end. You have to remember that Rails simply renders HTML in your browser (albeit using back-end data-backed objects), and consequently, the `partials` that you're calling with do nothing other than that.

The trick you need to remember is that your partials should *recycle* a particular number of elements on your page. The local variables / data you pass to them is therefore somewhat irrelevant in the grand scheme of things.

---

**Collection**

I believe you'll want to do the following:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: "restaurants", collection: @restaurant, as: :restaurant %>

#app/views/users/_restuarants.html.erb
<%= content_for :li do %>
    <%= link_to restaurant.name, user_restaurants_path(current_user, restaurant)  %>
<% end %>
```

If you back this up with the appropriate routing structure, it should work well for you:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   get :restaurant_id, action: :show, as: :restaurants # -> domain.com/users/:user_id/:restaurant_id
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
       user_id =  params[:restaurant_id].present? ? params[:user_id] : params[:id]
       @user = User.find user_id

       @restaurant = @user.restaurants.find params[:restaurant_id] if params[:restaurant_id]
       @campaigns = @restaurant.campaigns if @restaurant
   end
end
```

Not the way I'd do it personally, but it will certainly give you the ability to load the campaigns for a particular restaurant on your `users` show page.

---

**Structure**

Something important you need to consider is the *structure* of your application.

You mention you're a newbie at Rails - let me give you a quick introduction to how Rails-based applications should work. Because they're *object orientated*, you really need to base your flow on the objects / resources which you'll be calling.

You'll benefit from reading up on [object orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) software patterns - you need to make sure every time you load a "view" in Rails, that you're populating it with objects relative to the controller / model you're working with.

Here's what I mean:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      @restaurants = @user.restaurants
   end
end
```

Do you see how the structure of the data is built *from* the original `@user` object?

When designing the structure of your application, you need to appreciate the data you're going to show in each view. Specifically, you need to appreciate that if you have views for `users#show` - your primary focus needs to be on populating that view with the relevant `User` object